# How to display an EditText view 15dp below the top edge of an ImageView's drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, imageview, android-drawable

I want to display an `EditText` 15dp below the top of an `ImageView`. My `ImageView` is set to center horizontally and fill the parent `RelativeLayout` so the `EditText`'s position is messed up. On some devices it shows up almost above the `ImageView`. Any ideas on how I can show it exactly 15dp below the top edge of the `ImageView` so that it's fully contained within the drawable?

Thank you!

```
  <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image_view"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:textSize="39sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout seem to be correct you just need to use android:scaleType="fitStart" or centerCrop instead of [android:adjustViewBounds="true"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) and set ImageView width and height to match_parent or 320dp

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="39sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that saved me hours of pain (`android:scaleType="centerCrop"` worked). Bonus question: if I rotate the `ImageView` using `setRotation()`, do you know if there's an easy way to maintain the 15dp top margin for the `EditText`? The drawable's width and height are uneven, so I tried adding half of the difference between the `ImageView`'s height and width => (height-width)/2. The `EditText` is pushed up though. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I can be of help. I am not sure I really get your bonus question but why not rotate the RelativeLayout container or maybe you can share an image explaining your point

Comment: I'll upload an image later today to explain :). I need to keep the `EditText` view horizontal so I can't rotate the entire layout unfortunately.